# How do I manually register FluentValidation validators, in ASP.NET Core?

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, fluentvalidation

I'm using ASP.NET Core, with the built-in container.

Registration is supposed to be done [like so](http://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/blob/237ccfd581dcecf72209acdaabd4c41122fad98d/src/FluentValidation.AspNetCore/FluentValidationMvcExtensions.cs#L146):

```
services
  .AddMvc()
  .AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>())
```

This automatically:

1. configures FluentValidation
2. registers all validators found in the assembly

But I want to register my validators **manually**. How do I do that?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
// must first setup FV
services
    .AddMvc()
    .AddFluentValidation(fv => {});

// can then manually register validators
services.AddTransient<IValidator<Foo>, FooValidator>();
services.AddTransient<IValidator<Bar>, BarValidator>();
```

Comment: Is possible to add **AddFluentValidation** more than one times into my class library startup file?

Comment: This is now deprecated: https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1965

Answer (score 3):

You are going to want to start looking into using a ValidatorFactory. So instead of your call to add FluentValidation, your call would look something like this:

`.AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.ValidatorFactory = new MyValidatorFactory())`

You will need to register your validators in your IOC container. In your custom ValidatorFactory implementation you will need to override CreateInstance and have it resolve the validators for you using the IOC container.

https://github.com/JeremySkinner/FluentValidation/wiki/i.-IoC

Comment: Actually I tried something much simpler which works: `services.AddTransient<IValidator<Foo>, FooValidator>();` I'm curious why it works, and why your way is correct or not?

Comment: When you add your validators like that, are you still calling `.AddFluentValidation(fv => fv.RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining<Startup>())`

Comment: No I remove that auto-registration. Then manually register each one. And it just works. But I fear that `RegisterValidatorsFromAssemblyContaining` does more stuff that I'm missing, and it'll blow up at runtime.

Comment: So you haven't actually tested to see if that still validates your requests?

Comment: It does. But doesn't seem right. I'm sure there is more to it.

Comment: FYI this is now deprecated: https://github.com/FluentValidation/FluentValidation/issues/1965